# Re-activated users not receiving Google group emails

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-settings

I'm an administrator of a Google apps domain and we recently reactivated an account which was suspended for around 6 months. Regular emails to this user are working well but emails to a group to which this user belongs does not seem to reach the user.

I tried deleting the user from the group and adding him again, but to no avail.

What might be the problem? And what is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/Apps/K_yLOFFosSs). It suggested to check the email delivery setting and the spam folder. Here's another reference which might also help: [Not getting a group’s emails](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/70498?hl=en)

If you’re not getting emails from your group, check your email delivery setting:

1. Sign in to [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/).
2. Click **My Groups**.
3. Choose a group.
4. At the top right, click **My settings**.
5. Select **Membership and email settings**.
6. Check "Email delivery preference." Make sure that you haven’t selected "Don’t send email updates."
7. After making changes, click **Save**.